# On eigen-value of a particular type of permutation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A \in M(n,\mathbb R)$ be defined as $A:=(e_n \space \space e_1 ... \space e_{n-1})$ ; where $e_i$ is the standard $i$-th basis vector of $\mathbb R^n$ written as a column matrix .  I can see that $A^n=I$ . Now suppose $n$ is odd ; then can $A$ have a repeated  eigenvalue (in $\mathbb C$) ?

Comment: It's very easy to figure out the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: @CameronWilliams : I can see that any eigen-value is a $n$-th root of unity and if $n$ is odd then $1$ is an eigen-value ; but apart from that what else can we say ? Could you please elaborate on your comment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ has no repeated eigenvalue: the eigenvalues of $A$ includes all $n$th roots of $1$, and there are $n$ of those.

One quick way to see that this is the case is to know/guess the eigenvectors: note that for **any** $\lambda$ satisfying $\lambda^n = 1$, the vector
$$
(1,\lambda,\lambda^2, \cdots ,\lambda^{n-1})^T
$$
is an eigenvector of $A$. This means that each of $n$ different eigenvalues gets an eigenvector.

Comment: ah I see . Thanks , that helped

Answer (score 0):

It is well-known that $A = F_n D_n F_n^{-1}$, where: $F_n$ denotes the $n$-by-$n$ [*DFT matrix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix); $D_n := \text{diag}(1,\omega,\dots,\omega^{n-1})$; and $\omega := \exp(2\pi i/n)$.